# How come when I call this function it doesn't return my input? It says its returning support but it doesn't?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

// **Change needs_it_support so that it returns support:**
bool needs_it_support() {
  
  bool support;
  
  std::cout << "Hello. IT. Have you tried turning it off and on again? Enter 1 for yes, 0 for no.\n";
  std::cin >> support;
  return support;
}

int main() {
  
  // **Change the following line to print the function result:**
needs_it_support();  **calling function**
  
}
```

But nothing is getting printed out I just press 1 or 0 and I don't get anything returned back to me

Comment: The function is returning result. You are ignoring the result.

Comment: "**Change the following line to print the function result:**" the following line does not have any code to print the returned value

Comment: which part of the code did you expect to print the value of `support`? Don't confuse printing something on the screen and returning something from a function, those are two very different things

Comment: One problem with code comments is that very few read them. Don't be such a person.

Answer (score 1):

you should print result after returned from function in this case you should put something like this :

```
std::cout << needs_it_support() << std::endl;
```

or:

```
bool result  = needs_it_support();
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Comment: but im a little confused because what exactly does std::cout << (calling the function) do? does it still just execute all the code? and if so why does it not repeat all the outputs again?

Comment: @juicywrldy `std::cout << needs_it_support() << std::endl;` this code first execute needs_it_support function then result will return from this function after that result will be input for ostream(which is in this case `std::cout`) and then it will print.yes if you run  `std::cout << needs_it_support() << std::endl;` it will execute all of `needs_it_support`.